# Error when creating a new model in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

When I try to open or create a new model I get this error from Anylogic software:

could not initialize class com.anylogic.objectmodel.metadata.util.HideDisableValue.

Comment: Any model, even example models? If yes, maybe a corrupted installation? Did you try to reinstall? What else did you try? Help us help you :)

Comment: Yes, even example models. I tried reinstalling twice, but didn't work. It is weird because before it worked perfectly.

Comment: Deinstall and then delete the `.AnyLogicProfessional` folder in `C:\Users\YourUsername`. Then reinstall. Note that you must show hidden folders in Windows to see it in the first place

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I forgot to mention that this is the Anylogic PLE version, don't know if that matters...

Comment: I deleted the .AnyLogicPLE folder in C:\Users\YourUsername and reinstalled it but it didn't work :(

Comment: time for support@anylogic.com then :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your operating system doesn't have some .dll libraries required for proper work of the software. Please install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio

https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe

from

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/